# golang program does not execute as expected

Tags: go

I am working trough a course "Mastering Go Programming" by "Mina Andrawos". The following adapted code does not execute as expected:

**a) main.go -**
    package main

```
import (
 "fmt"
 "interfaces/linklist"
)

func main() {
    node := linklist.NewNode()
    node.SetValue(1)
    fmt.Println("Get Value: ", node.GetValue())
}
```

**b) linklist.go -**
    package linklist

```
// Node struct
type Node struct {
    next  *Node
    value int
}

// SetValue function
func (sNode Node) SetValue(v int) {

    sNode.value = v
}

// GetValue function
func (sNode Node) GetValue() int {

    return sNode.value
}

// NewNode constructor
func NewNode() Node {

    return Node{}
}
```

**Problem:**
The code "sNode.value = v" in "linklist.go" is never executed. The program outputs "0" instead of "1". In debug mode the "sNode.value = v" code is skipped when "node.SetValue(1)" is executed in the main function.

What must be done so that the program prints "Get Value: 1"?

**Environment**:

- OS: Ubuntu 16.04/64bit
- GO Version: 1.8.1
- Command to execute the program: go run main.go

Comment: Change your method receiver types from `Node` to `*Node`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Go, using a setter for a struct type does not work as anticipated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6476343/in-go-using-a-setter-for-a-struct-type-does-not-work-as-anticipated)