# How should one set singleton state in Go? (Or, why doesn't this work?)

Tags: go, singleton, state

Barring any conversation about whether singletons should be used (Yes, I know, antipattern, I've opted not to use it anyway), I'm confused as to why this doesn't work. I have state I'm trying to set within a singleton instance, but my method is not actually modifying the main instance.

What does hold is any initialization I pass when the singleton is instantiated.

At first I thought it was a nested struct problem, because I started with a `bar` in a `foo`, but then found it did the same thing with the primitive `val`.

In the off chance it matters, I'm running Go 1.12.7 on Mac OS Mojave.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

type foo struct {
    val   int
    state bar
}

type bar struct {
    inner int
}

var singleton *foo
var once sync.Once

func GetFoo() *foo {
    once.Do(func() {
        singleton = &foo{
            state: bar{inner: 0},
        }
    })
    return singleton
}

func (f foo) SetState() {
    f.val = 1
    f.state.inner = 1
}

func main() {

    f := GetFoo()
    fmt.Println(f)
    f.SetState()
    fmt.Println(f)

}
```

I would expect this to output:

```
&{0 {0}}
&{1 {1}}
```

Instead, I'm getting:

```
&{0 {0}}
&{0 {0}}
```

Comment: The problem is unrelated to the singleton.  Because the method has a value receiver, any changes made to the receiver argument are discarded when the method returns.

Comment: Ah, so the receiver is shadowing the global instance? How/why/when do receivers act like pass-by-value parameters?

Comment: All arguments, including the receiver, are passed by value in Go.  Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11810218/how-to-set-and-get-fields-in-structs-method, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6476343/using-a-setter-for-a-struct-type-does-not-work-as-anticipated,

Comment: Yeah, it is. Please flag if you can, I don't have the reputation to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Cerise spotted it immediately. I did not realize method receivers are essentially passed by value in Go. Therefore, to fix this example, the `SetState` signature just needs to be changed to `(f *foo) SetState()`